# Casting a void pointer to an arbitrary type pointer

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am attempting to do my own implementation of common data structures in C for my own learning benefit.  My current effort is a vector, and I want it to be able to hold a single arbitrary type (or at least type size, but isn't that all that really matters in C?).  My struct is as follows:

```
struct vector
{
    void *item;
    size_t element_size;
    size_t num_elements;
}
```

However, what I don't understand is how I can refer to specific elements in the *item array if the type is supposed to be arbitrary.  I know the element_size, but that doesn't help me with index referencing (e.g. item[5]) because void is not a type.  I figured it would be easiest to refer to the elements as byte offsets.  So if I was holding a vector of structs with size 12, item[5] would be at 12*5=60 bytes from item*.  However, I don't understand how to retrieve that data.  I know I want 12 bytes from item+60, but how would I make the compiler understand that?  Am I getting into preprocessor territory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` is measure in chars, so you can do this:

```
void *start_of_sixth_element = ((char*)item) + (5 * element_size);
```

Someone who knows what the type of each element is could then cast `start_of_sixth_element` to the correct type to use it.

`void*` is a bad choice in a way, since you can't do pointer arithmetic with `void*` pointers in standard C (there's a GNU extension to allow it, but for portable code you use `char*` or `unsigned char*` at least for the arithmetic).

Code that knows the correct type *before* applying the offset 5, could just do this:

```
correct_type *sixth_element = ((correct_type *)item) + 5;
```

*void is not a type*

It is a type, it's just not a "complete type". "Incomplete type" pretty much means the compiler doesn't know what a `void*` really points to.

Comment: Given a type, is there an easy way to find out the correct value of `element_size`? (I am thinking alignment requirements.)

Comment: @aix: given the type, `element_size` is `sizeof(type)`: the size of an object already includes any padding needed for alignment. Alignment depends how the memory pointed to by `item` was allocated. As long as it's allocated with `malloc(element_size*num_elements)` (and the multiplication doesn't overflow!) then there are no alignment issues, since `malloc` is "guaranteed" to return memory aligned for any object. I use snigger quotes because super-sized types for SIMD instructions are often excluded by implementations.

Comment: @aix, the `sizeof` operator takes alignment into account. For example, if `long` has 4-byte alignment, then `sizeof` applied to a `struct` containing a `long` and a `char` is 8.

Comment: I have been recommended to instead use unsigned int as my internal item[] type, which would hold addresses of the values that the container stores.  Would you recommend that instead of using void*?

Comment: @doubleshot: no, it's not possible to store a pointer value in an `unsigned int`. On 64 bit Windows or Linux, an address is 64 bits, but `unsigned int` is only 32 bits, so it's a complete non-starter. `void*` and `unsigned char*` can both reasonably be used to store the address of any object.

Comment: Thank you - I had success using a void** as my internal item array.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

The `void *` is a generic pointer type for any object pointer type. You have to know what type it points into in order to correctly cast the `void *` and dereference the pointer.

Here is an example with a `void *` object used with different pointer types.

```
void *p;
int a = 42, b;
double f = 3.14159, g;

p = &a;
b = *(int *) a;

p = &f;
g = *(double *) f;
```

Answer (score 0):

> So if I was holding a vector of structs with size 12, item[5] would be at 12*5=60 bytes from item*. However, I don't understand how to retrieve that data. I know I want 12 bytes from item+60, but how would I make the compiler understand that?

Say that your given type is `foo`. As you already understood, you need to reach the address at `item + (5 * 12)` then dereference the void pointer after casting it to `foo*`.

```
foo my_stuff = *(foo *)(item + 5 * 12);
```

You can also use `sizeof()` if you can determine at compile time the type of your data :

```
foo my_stuff = *(foo *)(item + 5 * sizeof(foo));
```